# Specifying deployment configuration settings for weblogic?

Tags: java, configuration, weblogic

I have a super lightweight weblogic application and I need access to a string that will change depending on the environment.  I've searched for a bit and all my options seem to require building classes and loaders etc.  However with the number of application configuration files weblogic has I'm fully expecting there to be a better place to store a single global property for quick reference that can be changed using the plan.xml file.

Comment: Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `plan.xml` during deployment time with entry as below to override `myEnvVariable` context variable value defined through context in `web.xml`. Details are provided at [**Oracle Website**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/deployment/wlplangenerator.html).

```
 <variable-definition>
  <variable>
      <name>myEnvVariable</name>
      <value>myEnvironmentDependentValue</value>
  </variable>
 </variable-definition>
```

You may want to create different `plan.xml` for different environments.

Context variable in `web.xml` can be defined as below:

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>myEnvVariable</param-name>
    <param-value>myEnvironmentDefaultValue/param-value>
 </context-param>
```

Context variables can be retrieved in server side using request object as below:

```
 String myEnvVariableString= getServletContext().getInitParameter("myEnvVariable");
```

Comment: This doesn't work to my knowledge as those values are not accessable at runtime, nor can they be retrieved via System.getenv or System.getProperty.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, please define the variable in `web.xml` first. I updated the answer with example. Through `plan.xml`, you are only overriding the value of the variable. You can very well retrieve this variable in server side from the context(added example in the answer).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if your looking for this(adding another answer).

1. Open `startWebLogic.cmd/startWebLogic.sh` available in your weblogic domain folder.
2. Add `set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dmy.environment=TestEnviroment` in the top section of the file 
     before it calls `call "%DOMAIN_HOME%\bin\startWebLogic.cmd" %*`
3. Save the file and restart the `Weblogic` server.

This variable is now present in the environment for usage.